# How to use Array of column names agaisnt a dataframe row inside map function and create a new DF

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame with 200 columns I created a Array from `df.columns`,

while iterating through dataframe df  how to  tell the row to select only those columns from row and create a new dataframe.

```
val df = df1.join.df2
val colNames = df.columns

df.map {  row =>
  val createnewDF = (row(colNames)
}
```

How to create the below line?

```
val createnewDF = (row(colNames)
```

Comment: `df.columns` will select all the column names into an array. so its useless to use the column names inside loop of each row of the dataframe. Please explain more and with clarity.

Answer (score 0):

If you are intending to select only limited number of `columns` from your joined `dataframe` then you need to create an `array` of those column names and use `select` method as

```
val colNames = Array("col1", "col2", "col4")
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val createnewdf = df.select(colNames.map(col): _*)
```

`df.columns` will select all column names into an `array` and I don't see any use of selecting columns inside loop of `dataframe rows` as that `dataframe` already has all the columns.

Moreover, you can change the values of selected columns inside the loop of rows. But looping `dataframe rows` is not recommended unless an [inbuilt function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html) is not defined.